# Does Beanstalk support older versions of PHP like 5.4?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am very new to Amazon Web Services and I am just trying to upload one of my applications to the Elastic Beanstalk instance I have obtained. My project is written in PHP and it runs best in 5.4. I zipped the content; created an application in my EB instance; and, uploaded the source code with the platform as PHP. By default, Elastic Beanstalk created the application with PHP version 7.3 (PHP 7.3 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.4. And, I do not have an option to choose a different version of it. The only other version I see in `platform change` is `PHP 7.3 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.3`.

Any idea on how to add PHP 5.4 to the platform and make my application use it?

Comment: PHP 5.4 was end-of-lifed and has been dangerously insecure to run for nearly *five years*. Time to fix your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, using the EB CLI, `eb init -p php-5.4` did the trick. I did not have to use a custom platform or docker to downgrade the version of an existing application. To use a version other than the latest version for the application, using the CLI with the `-p` option takes care of the job.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is [Elastic Beanstalk Custom Platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html):

> AWS Elastic Beanstalk supports custom platforms. A custom platform is a more advanced customization than a custom image in several ways. A custom platform lets you develop an entire new platform from scratch, customizing the operating system, additional software, and scripts that Elastic Beanstalk runs on platform instances. This flexibility enables you to build a platform for an application that uses a language or other infrastructure software, for which Elastic Beanstalk doesn't provide a managed platform.

Personally, I would consider the effort needed to upgrade the application to the latest supported 7.x runtime. Legacy software platforms are a potential security hazard.

Comment: I agree with that, but this is just a tryout focusing on performing a version degrade to an available platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker based deployment in beanstalk as an alternative.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try this today